# Remover espaços via Update

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, string, sql-update

Eu tenho um campo chamado `titulo`, na tabela `noticias`. Infelizmente, devido ao esquecer do comando `trim` do PHP, tem vários títulos com espaço no inicio e fim da *string*. Como  posso via SQL (MySQL) atualizar os títulos removendo os espaços no inicio e fim, em um único comando SQL?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e ajudar a todos entender isso. Também pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

Usando a função [`TRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim):

```
UPDATE INTO noticiais SET titulo = TRIM(titulo);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/Trim.sql).